# relative and absolute html path?

Tags: html

The code snippet in html format is showing as below.
there are three requirements listed below for reference as well.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Images and Links - Fast Broccoli!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Fast Broccoli! - About Us</h1>
            <!--
                Use images and links to build an "About Us" page for Fast Broccoli!,
                the world's first one-hour organic produce delivery service.

            You'll need:
            1. A main image with source: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Broccoli_and_cross_section_edit.jpg
                  and alt description: Fast Broccoli!'s Logo
            2. A link to the relative path: index.html
                with the text: Return Home
            3. A second link to the absolute path: https://shop.fastbrocolli.com
                The link should target a new browser window.
                The link should contain an image
                    with source: images/cabbage.png
                   -->
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Honestly, it looks like you want us to do your homework. There is not even a question here.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>This strangely looks like a school project. I could just give you the solution to your assignment, but I believe it would be better if you learn it.
Hope you enjoy!</sup>

## Image Tag

Here's an example `img` tag from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp):

```
 <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face">
```

This is pretty simple. The source is `smiley.gif` and the alt description is `Smiley face`. Now do you know how to make your own image tag? Otherwise, click the link above for more details.

## Links

#### Relative

A relative link is, well, relative. Where it goes depends on where the current URL.

A relative link is anything that does not begin  `http://`, `https://,` file:///`, etc.

In the most basic sense, it's the current URL + the relative path. (Less simple, it's telling the browser it's in the same folder as the current page).

*Example*: If I added a link on this page that looks like:

```
<a href="hi.html">Click me</a>
 
It would go to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361572/relative-and-absolute-html-path/hi.html

Because:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361572/relative-and-absolute-html-path + hi.html
```

If it begins with a forward slash (`/`), it will take the domain of the site and add to it. (Less simple, it's telling the browser the file is in the root directory of the site).

*Example*: If I added a link on this page that looks like:

```
<a href="/hi.html">Click me</a>
 
It would go to:
https://stackoverflow.com/hi.html

Because:
https://stackoverflow.com + hi.html
```

#### Absolute

An absolute path is absolute. It doesn't add to the end, but is an entirely new domain.

*Example*: If I added a link on this page that looks like:

```
<a href="http://example.com/">Click me</a>
 
It would go to:
http://example.com/

Because it begins with http://
```

## Notes

In all the examples, the text of the links was "Click me".

More info on [file paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp).

More info on the [target attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp). (Allows you to "target a new browser window.")

Comment: Is `/` not relative? I thought it was considered root-relative, rather than doc-relative?

Comment: Even starting a path with `/` is a relative path (relative to the root of the document, which is in some folder in a filesystem somewhere) is my point. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing) "An absolute path begins with a forward slash (/)," is incorrect. That's a root-relative path. `./` is document relative. `http://`, `c://`are absolute

Comment: That said, I see where that idea would come from in a unix filesystem. Great answer none the less. But if we're talking web-servers, the `/` takes you to the root of your public-directory... not the root of the actual file-system. So it's still a relative-path, just relative to the root of the folder the incoming request is mapped to. Food for thought. Great answer, I'm just being nit-picky & thought you'd like to know. Hell, I might be wrong :)

Comment: @admcfajn Gotcha! Thanks for the catch. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp clear shows that `/images/picture.jpg` is relative.

Answer (score 1):

i m getting this error "I can't find your main image with src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Broccoli_and_cross_section_edit.jpg". Please add it."

```
    <h1>Fast Broccoli! - About Us</h1>


  <img src="Broccoli_and_cross_section_edit.jpg" alt="Fast Broccoli!'s Logo"
       style="width: 60px;"/>

  <a href="index.html">Return Home</a>


  <a href="https://shop.fastbrocolli.com">
  <img src="images/cabbage.png" />
  </a>
```

Comment: No `\\` needed here, or ever (unless escaping special characters).